# Central alignment using margin auto does not work in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a footer menu which should be centered horizontally on the screen with the elements inside then centered horizontally within the footer container (see image below). This works fine in all browsers apart from IE7 (which is the lowest version of IE we wish to support). I cannot understand why this is not working. I have reproduced the code here in this fiddle however the fiddle also seems to align it incorrectly (so I can provide a link to the site if needs be):

http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/tz5Ym/

Does anyone have any clues as to why this is not working in IE7? Do I need to perform an IE7 specific hack?

Before anyone else states the obvious:

- Yes , I'm already using margin:auto for horizontal margins.
- Yes, I've declared my Doctype

  ```
  jme1988
  ```

Correct Display:
[image: Correct Display]

IE7 Display:
[image: IE7 Display]

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> have u given the std's

Comment: If you look at the code in my fiddle and indeed the title, margin:auto does not appear to be working.

Comment: Yes I have. I'm not an amateur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding doesn't seem to work on non-block elements so I had to use:

```
display: block;
```

to force IE7 to accept the styling.

Answer (score 3):

Are you willing to use CSS hacks in your code? If so, you can target specific IE versions using know bugs in the CSS implementations for each browser. See the [NetTuts post on the subject](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/).

For example:

```
body {  
  color: red; /* all browsers, of course */  
  color : green\9; /* IE8 and below */  
  *color : yellow; /* IE7 and below */  
  _color : orange; /* IE6 */  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When using an absolute width for the element which you would like to center, using the following is a workaround for older Internet Explorers:

```
div.center{
  width:1024px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-512px;
}
```

Also: did you declare your doctype?

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work either and is not cross-browser compatible.